# KendoReact TabStrip has missing wrapper div

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to get a vertical TabStrip setup in my React app.

Test render currently looks like this:

```
public render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <TabStrip
                    selected={this.state.selected}
                    onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                    tabPosition="left"
                >
                    <TabStripTab title="T" />
                    <TabStripTab title="T" />
                </TabStrip>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

Instead of this showing a vertical TabStrip, it's showing as horizontal.

When I look at chrome DevTools, I can see a difference in my app and the demo app at https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/tabstrip/tabs/

I seem to be missing a div `<div class="k-tabstrip-items-wrapper k-vstack">` which should come below the initial TabStrip div.
If I manually add this div into the chrome DevTools, the TabStrip is vertical, as expected.

I've tried adding a div to the TabStrip in React, but it returns an error

> "Warning: TabStripTab(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`."

Any ideas?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. You can check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ygcnay?file=app/main.jsx) example that contains the code you've posted.

Comment: @tromgy that's weird. Don't know why I'm facing this particular issue.. I will add I'm trying to render this code inside of another div, but I don't see why that would be an issue